# GDAL "dll not found" error

Tags: gdal

After following step by step the instructions here to install GDAL: http://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows

When I run from osgeo import gdal, I get the following:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How could I fix this?

I use python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64b), Windows 10 (64b)

Comment: If you are using 64bit python, you'll also need to verify that you've used 64bit GDAL as well. The tutorial you posted instructs you to use 32bit.

Answer (score 3):

GDAL core dll's are not on your system path. Perhaps you are running Python on a command window that was opened during the last installation steps? Environment variables changes are not propagated to running "cmd" processes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by installing this

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/#krb5-1.20

64-bit MSI Installer kfw-4.1-amd64.msi

Requires restart.